# How can I combine a tv signal from the wall to an amplified antenna into my digital TV?

Tags: tv-antenna, coaxial-cable, television, interference

I am having a very difficult time receiving OTA DTV signals and want to combine a few different antennas. I purchased a splitter that actually combines different signals, and it works, but this is where my problem begins.

For whatever reason, i can't receive ABC using any antenna I've been able to connect. There's a coaxial connection that goes into the walls that I decided to scan out of desperation and for whatever reason, I can receive ABC on this connection. I have no idea what's on the other side of this connection, all i know is that ABC comes in perfectly without any signal fluctuation.

So, that's where the combiner comes in. I connected one end to wall coax connection, and the other end to my antenna. This all works fine.

The problem is that the antenna is powered. And without the power, the antenna is 1/10th as useful. With the power, ABC becomes completely distorted.

So my question is how do i stop my powered antenna from affecting the signal that gives me ABC without pulling the power from the antenna which effectively renders it useless?

Comment: Where do you live? How far are you from the broadcast tower? I have an HDTV Antenna as well and just by moving it around and finding the best spot, you can probably get ABC. Also, I live pretty close to the broadcast tower and when I hook up the powered amplifier, it does more harm then good. I barely get any stations with the powered amplifier.

Comment: Tyson, that should be added as an answer! That's exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: @Tyson please add your answer under answers, not in the comments.